# Getting the correct data from selected item using useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get data only from specific item selected, but unfortunately I don't know how to approach this.

This is what I tried:

My route looks like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/explore">
      <ExploreCard closetItems={closetItems} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/explore/:id">
      <ExploreDetail
        closetItems={closetItems}
        setClosetItems={setClosetItems}
      />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

And the fetch from API:

```
const [closetItems, setClosetItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getClosets = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://api.npoint.io/eb35d003cd0c1991c6aa"
      );
      const closet = response.data;
      setClosetItems(closet);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  getClosets();
}, []);
```

Then I am mapping through the items like so:

```
{closetItems.map((list) => (
  <div key={list.id}>
    <h4>
      Name: <Link to={`/explore/${list.id}`}>{list.name}</Link>
    </h4>
  </div>
))}
```

Here what happens using code above:

1. I get to the correct path (if I choose an item with ID of 2 then path is `/explore/2`)
2. Path `/explore/2` shows detailed data of all items not only of id=2

Here how it looks like:

```
const ExploreDetails = ({ closetItems, setClosetItems }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    {closetItems
      // .filter((list) => list.id === id)
      .map((list) => (
        <div key={list.id}>
          <h2>Name: {list.name}</h2>
          <h4>Category: {list.email}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
```

How can I fetch data only of selected item with `id = 2` ?

Comment: With defining ref on that element, you can understand which element is clicked and define data-value with ids and check it by clicking. I don't know you need to forward the ref or not, as I didn't test your code practically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All params of URL are as string type.

You can use **parseInt()** method to convert to integer type.

```
const ExploreDetails = ({ closetItems, setClosetItems }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
   return (
           {closetItems
              .filter((list) => list.id === parseInt(id))
              .map((list) => (
                <div  key={list.id}>
                    <h2>Name: {list.name}</h2>
                    <h4>Category: {list.email}</h4>
                </div>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding from the answer of Javad Masoudian, if you want to return *only* the element that matches some condition, you can also use `Array#find` then use it like so:

```
//...
const params = useParams();

const item = closetItems.find(({ id }) => id === parseInt(params.id));

//...
return (
  <>
    <h2>Name: {item.name}</h2>
    <h4>Category: {item.email}</h4>
  </>
);
```

This way you don't get back an array but instead the object itself that you can use directly.